# Is there anyway simplify this expression

Tags: regex

I'm looking for help to simplify this regular expression.

```
([0-9]{9})|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7})
```

This expression tests true for the following values

```
12-3456789
123456789
123-45-6789
```

Comment: why do you think it needs simplifying?

Comment: Apart from changing all `[0-9]` to just `\d`?

Comment: One way to shorten is: `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{7})`

Comment: If the separate capture groups for the different formats are important... there isn't really anything you could do... other than using `\d` I suppose... but honestly for this kind of thing I usually just strip out the non-numbers, make sure there is the right amount of numbers... and then format however I like

Comment: @smerny i believed this could be done much better or shorter. If it can't be or need not be then I'm ok. Thanks.

Comment: I've ended up with this `^(\d{2}-?\d{7}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use,

```
^([0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})$
```

`-?` turns the previous token `-` to optional.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uJ7wA6/1)